# ValueError when trying to create df of summary statistics

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a dataframe that's simply two columns with counts. Every time I try to put the counts in, I get this error:

`ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`

Here's my code:

```py
BoxTrackingSummary_df = pd.DataFrame()
BoxTrackingSummary_df_columns = ['School - Exams Tracked', 'School - Exams Not Tracked']

summary_group = BoxTrackingReport_df.groupby('Tracked At A Site?').agg('count')['All Box Tracked Sites']


BoxTrackingSummary_df['School - Exams Tracked'] = summary_group['NO']
BoxTrackingSummary_df['School - Exams Not Tracked'] = summary_group['TRACKED']
```

My summary group returns:

```
Tracked At A Site?
NO          3
TRACKED    18
Name: All Box Tracked Sites, dtype: int64
```

I want a dataframe that looks like:

```
School - Exams Tracked         School - Exams Not Tracked
                    18                                  3
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_comm\server.py", line 34, in handle
    self.processor.process(iprot, oprot)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 266, in process
    self.handle_exception(e, result)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 254, in handle_exception
    raise e
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 263, in process
    result.success = call()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\third_party\thriftpy\_shaded_thriftpy\thrift.py", line 228, in call
    return f(*(args.__dict__[k] for k in api_args))
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_console_utils.py", line 236, in getArray
    return pydevd_thrift.table_like_struct_to_thrift_struct(array, name, roffset, coffset, rows, cols, format)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_thrift.py", line 602, in table_like_struct_to_thrift_struct
    return TYPE_TO_THRIFT_STRUCT_CONVERTERS[type_name](array, name, roffset, coffset, rows, cols, format)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_thrift.py", line 545, in dataframe_to_thrift_struct
    array_chunk.headers = header_data_to_thrift_struct(rows, cols, dtypes, col_bounds, col_to_format, df, dim)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_thrift.py", line 577, in header_data_to_thrift_struct
    col_header.max = col_format % bounds[1]
```

My workflow is that I create separate dataframes and put them through tests. My test utility is optimized to accept dfs and not series, so even for a simple summary table I'd like that as a df.

Comment: Why don't you do a transpose?

Comment: It looks like a series.. can't transpose a series

Comment: (unless of course you make it `to_frame`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to use .loc:

`BoxTrackingSummary_df['School - Exams Tracked'] = summary_group['NO']
BoxTrackingSummary_df['School - Exams Not Tracked'] = summary_group['TRACKED']`